# What types of Storage Account services can be used with customer managed keys in Azure?

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-storage

An azure storage can contain blob, file share, table, and queue types.  Of these, what types of services can be currently encrypted using customer managed keys?  I cannot find a definitive answer in the documentation. Can you please provide relevant link to the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems both of them can be protected by customer managed keys. support for blob storage is GA from last august.

> Data in Blob storage and Azure Files is always protected by
> customer-managed keys when customer-managed keys are configured for
> the storage account.

The doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/customer-managed-keys-overview?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#customer-managed-keys-for-queues-and-tables

And Create an account that supports customer-managed keys for tables and queues:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/account-encryption-key-create?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fqueues%2Ftoc.json&tabs=powershell